# Reference for studying polar coordinate

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, polar-coordinates

There is a theorem about justification of polar-coordinate in Folland-Real analysis p.78.

I find it somewhat terse (Maybe it's just me)..

I guess this kind of transform is possible even when $S^{n-1}$is defined to be $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : ||x||=1\}$ where $||\cdot||$ is an arbitrary norm, not just 2-norm.

This is not the only reason I find it terse.

Is there a webpage or a text treating the polar-coordinate with more explanations neatly?

Comment: What exactly is too terse for you?

Comment: @Thomas For one reason, terms are not really defined here. For instance, you can see the definition of "Push-forward measure" in Daniel-A Concise introduction to the theory of integration. Things are really well-defined here and he touches polar-coordinate deeply and slowly. (I don't like his approach though, the book is not well-organized in my opinion). I want a text devotes at least a single chapter to introduce the polar coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, the notion of *polar coordinates* in $\Bbb R^2$ can be reformulated in the following form:

> Every nonzero vector $v$ can be uniquely written in the form $v=\lambda\cdot e_\varphi$ where $\lambda>0$ is a scalar, and $e_\varphi\in S^1\ =\{x\,:\,\|x\|_2=1\}$.

Here, the unit vectors $e_\varphi$ are in a one-to-one correspondence to the angles $\varphi\,\in [0,2\pi)$, by measuring the angle from the positive ray of the $x$-axis towards the positive ray of the $y$-axis.

Observing that $\lambda$ will be $\|v\|_2$, in this form this has a straightforward generalization to *any normed space* $(X,\|\_\|)$:

> Every nonzero vector $v\in X$ can be uniquely written in the form $v=\lambda\cdot v_1$ where $\lambda>0$ is a scalar, and $v_1\in \{x\,:\,\|x\|=1\}$.

And, of course, we must have $\lambda=\|x\|$ again.