# An integral about radial function.

Tags: calculus, lebesgue-integral, spherical-coordinates

If $f$ is a radial function and $f(x)=f_0(|x|)$, I want to show $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(u)e^{-2\pi ix \cdot u}du=\int_{0}^{\infty}f_0(s)\left(\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}} e^{-2\pi i |x| s(x' , u')}du'\right)s^{d-1}ds.$$

My trying is taking $s=|u|$ and applying the spherical coordinate transformation.  I don't know where is the $|x|s$ in the power of $e$ in the RHS comes from. Besides, where should I use the function $f$ is radial in the calculation?

Is there any special integral formulas about radial functions used here?

Thanks a  lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general form (I think that it is in Folland's blue book) of the change of variables is:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R^d}}g(x)dx = \int_0^\infty  \left( \int_{S^{d-1}} g(r\omega) d\omega \right) r^{d-1} dr = \int_{S^{d-1}}  \left( \int_0^\infty g(r\omega) r^{d-1}dr \right) d\omega,$$ 
where $\omega$ denotes a direction on the sphere and $d\omega$ denotes the sphere surface measure, and $r$ denotes the radius. (Note: the $r^{d-1}$ is a scaling factor from integrating on spheres of radius $r$.) So, $r\omega$ denotes an arbitrary point in $\mathbb{R}^d$. In particular, for $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ nonzero, $y = |y|\frac{y}{|y|} = r\omega$.

Keep in mind. If $f$ is radial, then $f(r\omega)$ only depends on $r$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am beginning to understand. The $u′$ in the problem is the direction on the sphere. Also, for this form of the change of variables, where can I find it? Is it a spherical coordinate transformation? Does the Folland's blue book is Real analysis? Is it a transformation from the locally compact group? Sorry for my lots of questions and I was stuck in this transformation for a long time.T-T

Comment: It is definitely in the appendix of Stein and Shakarchi's Fourier Analysis (part 1 of their analysis series). Some references: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658241/proof-of-polar-coordinates-theorem-in-evans-pde-book https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696060/reference-for-studying-polar-coordinate https://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~loftin/ra2/hw1hints.pdf

Comment: It is in Folland's Real Analysis section 2.7. Stein and Shakarchi only does it for continuous functions, I believe, and given chapter 2 of Folland, I think that it will do it in a lot of generality.

Comment: Okay, really appreciate for your great help!